# How to get other/insecure hashes in python hashlib

Tags: python, hashlib, md2

Using hashlib...

> hashlib.algorithms_available
>   {'sha256', 'sha512', 'md5-sha1', 'shake_256', 'sha512_224', 'md4', 'sha384', 'mdc2', 'md5', 'sha224', 'sha512_256', 'sha3_384', 'ripemd160', 'sha3_256', 'sha1', 'whirlpool', 'sha3_224', 'shake_128', 'sm3', 'sha3_512', 'blake2b', 'blake2s'}

how do I get MD2, ripemd128, ripemd256, ripemd320, etc?

supposedly these are chained in from openssl but nothing i have done has made any differences.

I was also able to use CRC32 and ADLER32  via zlib, but I don't see CRC8, CRC16 either.

Edit:  openssl has MD2 enabled, but it won't show up in hashlib :(

```
openssl  help
Standard commands
asn1parse         ca                ciphers           cms               
crl               crl2pkcs7         dgst              dhparam           
dsa               dsaparam          ec                ecparam           
enc               engine            errstr            gendsa            
genpkey           genrsa            help              list              
nseq              ocsp              passwd            pkcs12            
pkcs7             pkcs8             pkey              pkeyparam         
pkeyutl           prime             rand              rehash            
req               rsa               rsautl            s_client          
s_server          s_time            sess_id           smime             
speed             spkac             srp               storeutl          
ts                verify            version           x509              

Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md2               
md4               md5               mdc2              rmd160            
sha1              sha224            sha256            sha3-224          
sha3-256          sha3-384          sha3-512          sha384            
sha512            sha512-224        sha512-256        shake128          
shake256          sm3               

Cipher commands (see the `enc' command for more details)
aes-128-cbc       aes-128-ecb       aes-192-cbc       aes-192-ecb       
aes-256-cbc       aes-256-ecb       aria-128-cbc      aria-128-cfb      
aria-128-cfb1     aria-128-cfb8     aria-128-ctr      aria-128-ecb      
aria-128-ofb      aria-192-cbc      aria-192-cfb      aria-192-cfb1     
aria-192-cfb8     aria-192-ctr      aria-192-ecb      aria-192-ofb      
aria-256-cbc      aria-256-cfb      aria-256-cfb1     aria-256-cfb8     
aria-256-ctr      aria-256-ecb      aria-256-ofb      base64            
bf                bf-cbc            bf-cfb            bf-ecb            
bf-ofb            camellia-128-cbc  camellia-128-ecb  camellia-192-cbc  
camellia-192-ecb  camellia-256-cbc  camellia-256-ecb  cast              
cast-cbc          cast5-cbc         cast5-cfb         cast5-ecb         
cast5-ofb         des               des-cbc           des-cfb           
des-ecb           des-ede           des-ede-cbc       des-ede-cfb       
des-ede-ofb       des-ede3          des-ede3-cbc      des-ede3-cfb      
des-ede3-ofb      des-ofb           des3              desx              
idea              idea-cbc          idea-cfb          idea-ecb          
idea-ofb          rc2               rc2-40-cbc        rc2-64-cbc        
rc2-cbc           rc2-cfb           rc2-ecb           rc2-ofb           
rc4               rc4-40            seed              seed-cbc          
seed-cfb          seed-ecb          seed-ofb          sm4-cbc           
sm4-cfb           sm4-ctr           sm4-ecb           sm4-ofb
```

Comment: Package `pycrypto` http://pydoc.net/pycrypto/2.6.1/ has md2, ripemd, etc.

Comment: only ripemd160, which i already have successfully.  But it does have MD2.